# ImportError: cannot import name 'Color' from 'colour'

Tags: python, colors, pip, manim

I am trying to install [Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) in my elementary OS . After installing when i tried to open the example_scenes.py by `python3.7 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl` , i am getting the following error :

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/home/zarif98sjs/InstallManim/manim_3Feb/manim.py", line 3, in <module> import manimlib.extract_scene File "/home/zarif98sjs/InstallManim/manim_3Feb/manimlib/extract_scene.py", line 9, in <module> from manimlib.scene.scene import Scene File "/home/zarif98sjs/InstallManim/manim_3Feb/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 8, in <module> from manimlib.animation.animation import Animation File "/home/zarif98sjs/InstallManim/manim_3Feb/manimlib/animation/animation.py", line 6, in <module> from manimlib.mobject.mobject import Mobject File "/home/zarif98sjs/InstallManim/manim_3Feb/manimlib/mobject/mobject.py", line 8, in <module> from colour import Color ImportError: cannot import name 'Color' from 'colour' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/colour/__init__.py)`

I tried `sudo pip3 install colour` and `sudo pip3 install color` but still facing the same issue .
Any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Were these libraries installed successfully? If so uninstall and do it again. Also, try installing [brew](https://brew.sh/) and installing packages through it. Another option would be, just follow the instructions on [video](https://youtu.be/uZj_GQc6pN4) + google

Comment: I got help and solved this using python -m pip . The problem was happening because of 2 version of python installed and pip was not referring to the correct version .

Comment: @Zarif You could write an answer and accept your answer, so your answer can be useful for later users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from Manim discord community and solved this using `python -m pip install color` and `python -m pip install colour` . The problem was happening because of 2 version of python installed and pip was not referring to the correct version

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying the module colour.py from the python2 directory to the python3 directory? took me weeks of trying things out to fix it

'''
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/colour.py /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/colour.py
'''